# Vue.js 2: Are package.json dependencies bundled in the dist version at build?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

This may sound basic, but I've been unable to find the answer in my research.

I have an app built in Vue.js 2. I have just received a bunch of warnings from github that about 30 of my dependencies in package.json have vulnerabilities.

Does this affect the built dist version that's live or is it just the src version in order to build the dist version?

And if they are, how can I tell which dependencies are actually used in the build?

Comment: Dependencies are what you are using in your app… so yes, this affects you.

Comment: Whether or not they're in the build and whether that vulnerability actually impacts your users depends on how you're using the packages. There's no general answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. Is there a way to tell which ones are used in build?

Comment: There is: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer. Nuxt gets shipped with it. For pure Vue you find for sure a tutorial online.